# чем in comparisons - what am I missing?

Tags: перевод, грамматика, значения, словоупотребление

In this passage the presence of **больше** and **чем** clearly indicates a comparison, however it's not clear to me what is being contrasted. This is an article about the possibility of Russian becoming an language of international communication. [Точка зрения | Русский как язык международного общения](http://postnauka.ru/talks/22889)

To me, this says: ...Russian is a language, which makes it possible to grasp, learn and convey much more *than it's modern-day users*. (???)

> С одной стороны, русский безусловно является мировым языком во всех значениях слова «мировой»: он и один из пяти официальных языков ООН, и он язык, с помощью которого можно гораздо больше понять, узнать и рассказать, чем это делают современные его носители.

Obviously I'm missing the point, because my version wouldn't be a good argument for the promotion of Russian as a language of international communication - in fact, it makes no sense at all. What am I missing?

Comment: By the way, this website is a great example of that statement. Russian speakers (and mostly native) talk with each other about Russian language in English.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov: that's an excellent point, Dmitry. Even on a site devoted to Russian, the prevailing language of communication is English. So ultimately, it would probably be up to Russians themselves to globalize their language.

Comment: Also would be nice to share link to english conversation and discussion there, because I do not see it. I do not like idea about superiority of some languages,  but one of obvious reasons to use english - to promote their ideas about the language in english speaking community, which is even not near to be 100% native.

Comment: @MolbOrg: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand what you wrote, but if you're asking for a link to the article, it's in my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual translation would be

> Russian is a language, which makes it possible to grasp, learn and convey much more than it's modern-day users **do**.

Note the bold **do** - it's the translation of Russian *делают*. Essentially the phrase is saying that people use it less than they can.

The actual comparison here is between *можно делать (понять, узнать, рассказать)* and *делают*.

Comment: So in other words, his argument is that Russian has much more potential for international validity and widespread use than its modern speakers give it?

Comment: @CocoPop I think the key here is _во всех значениях_--most likely he meant the colloquial meaning of _мировой_ = great, i. e. it's so great that even native speakers don't use its full potential.

Comment: @CocoPop Generally, you're correct, that's more or less what the phrase means, although I'd say it's close to _than its modern speakers utilise_.

Comment: @Aleks: Ok, I think I understand his reasoning: he makes two points in its support: (1) it's one of the five official languages of the UN; and (2) it's capable of a lot more (global) comprehension, acquisition and communicative force than it's modern-day (native) speakership gives it.